# Dynamically executing multiple BPEL files in Java

Tags: java, deployment, bpel

I have some 50 variations of a BPEL process with minor changes in the internal algorithms, but all are having the same request interface and the same response type, which means they all are described by one WSDL file.

My question is how to dynamically deploy and execute all these BPEL processes in an efficient way, using Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SoapUI with Groovy scripts for this. Create a series of requests and have the Groovy script execute them in sequence. Or just a SoapUI test suite with multiple requests.